# Verify Database not updating all tables

Tags: database, crystal-reports, verify

We are getting ready to release a new version of our database and I am trying to update our standard documents in Crystal Reports 2013 via Database > Verify Database. I am getting messages about some of the tables in the document being updated, but not all of the ones with updated schema. I know that I am connecting to the correct database, because if I try to add a new instance of the same table, it will have the correct fields. Is there a way to force a particular table to update?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the the table that was not updated was being pulled from a different SQL view -- when that view was updated to the new schema, Verify Database could be rerun and it found and updated all of the tables